# web.php already saved but still given the wrong route

Tags: laravel, routes

I'm sorry if you are confused or misunderstood because i can't explain it very well. I already saved my web.php but i didn't know why it won't read my new saved web.php. it will read my previously saved web.php which is the view of login.blade.php, my new saved web.php is the view of download.blade.php and it still the view of login.blade.php. i thought that maybe it always return to the view of my previously saved web.php.

Previously in web.php:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('login');
});
```

Previously in the terminal

```
/css/login.css
```

New saved web.php:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('download');
});
```

After saved web.php in terminal:

```
/css/login.css
```

And after i make a new route like:

```
Route::get('/help', function () {
    return view('help');
});
```

and when i use /help it says that 404|Page Not Found
And of course i already make the new help.blade.php and the css

Please help thank you

[Here's the code in web.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jlbwb.png)

Comment: [Route Caching](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#route-caching) maybe? Try running `php artisan route:clear`

Comment: Glad it works. I'll quickly make it an answer you can accept so the question gets marked as solved. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `php artisan route:list` to show which routes have been set from your `web.php`.
If changes in your `web.php` don't reflect in that list or on your site chances are your routes are cached. In that case, run

```
php artisan route:clear
```

to clear the cache and re-read from your `web.php` file.

More on the topic:
[Route Caching](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#route-caching)

Answer (score 0):

Try `php artisan route:clear` to remove the route cache file
Or `php artisan optimize:clear` to remove the cached bootstrap files (all cached from your app)